# how to add uniquely new object in an array along with sort and slice method in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to add new object to an array but i want to ignore them if it is already exist. after that i want to sort the array field based on some object field. and at the end i want to slice that array field in specific limit.
I'm use $push method in [mongodb example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) which work fine but it add duplicate object:

```js
db.students.updateOne(
   { _id: 5 },
   {
     $push: {
       quizzes: {
          $each: [ { wk: 5, score: 8 }, { wk: 6, score: 7 }, { wk: 7, score: 6 } ],
          $sort: { score: -1 },
          $slice: 3
       }
     }
   }
)
```

I'm trying to change the $push to $addToSet but mongodb say:

> $addToSet does not guarantee a particular ordering of elements in the modified set.

so I'm trying to do this work with `aggregation pipeline`, after several try and write something like this:

```js
db.collection(collection).updateOne(
      {
        _id: updateId,
      },
      [
        {
          $set: {
            [relatedRel]: {
              $concatArrays: [
                {
                  $cond: {
                    if: { $in: [updatedDoc, `$${relatedRel}`] },
                    then: [],
                    else: [updatedDoc],
                  },
                },
                { $slice: [`$${relatedRel}`, relatedRelation.limit] },
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    );
```

it work whiteout `$sort` but it not working after i add `$sort` in any place of aggregation even within a `$concatArrays` or after that.

I know we can do this by writing 2 query with `bulk` but i want to do this with just 1 query.

Comment: Are you looking for [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) rather than $sort?

Comment: somehow detect the $sortArray and execute the update operator but with weird result, in some situation the first field is incorrect and in some other add object many times.

Comment: You'd need to update your answer with details to show us what you're seeing in a reproducible manner. Ideally put some sample documents and aggregation into https://mongoplayground.net/ and share it

Comment: tanx for offering mongoplayground.net, I'm trying in this site and finding the right solution: https://mongoplayground.net/p/J1kbh6bXo9l

Comment: I have another question: it there any performance issues in my answer, if it has performance issue please offer me the better way

Comment: That playground looks like it is for a totally different schema? What happened to students and quizzes? Furthermore, when you talk about performance issues and the right solution, it's not clear what either of those things mean. If the mongoplayground link you shared is supposed to be the answer to your question, then you should add an answer (not a comment) here about it. If you have questions about its performance, you should edit your question to include a link to it and describe what performance goals or concerns you have with it.